# How to use sameSite option of Node module "csurf"

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm setting up a Node.js server, installing the csurf module, and trying to set up "SameSitePoricy" as a CSRF measure. I set sameSite options as below, but sameSite doesn't become True
It remained “undefined”. (In req.session)
Is the setting method wrong? Or the wrong place to see?

I changed the setting as follows, but it was NG.

```
app.use(csrf({
  cookie: { sameSite: 'Strict' }
}));
```

```
var csrf = require('csurf');
app.use (csrf ({
sameSite: true
}));
```

I expect the output of "sameSite:Strict", but the actual output is "undefined".

Comment: Check your cookies with the dev tools, not on the server side.

Comment: @Roland Starke Thank you! checking for dev tools!